# Twin Data returned by GetTwinAsync is different depending on VS project type

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-iot-hub

I am getting different Twin Data from "registryManager.GetTwinAsync(deviceId)" depending on which type of Project i am using.

In a console app I am (correctly) getting:

> Twin Data: {"deviceId":"myFirstDevice","etag":"AAAAAAAAAAQ=","properties":{"desired":{"CamStatus":"off","$metadata":{"$lastUpdated":"2017-07-18T08:33:48.5224455Z","$lastUpdatedVersion":4,"CamStatus":{"$lastUpdated":"2017-07-18T08:33:48.5224455Z","$lastUpdatedVersion":4}},"$version":4},"reported":{"$metadata":{"$lastUpdated":"2017-05-20T19:35:34.7568052Z"},"$version":1}}}

In an Azure Function I am getting:

Json Data: {"DeviceId":"myFirstDevice","Tags":[],"Properties":{"Desired":[{"Key":"CamStatus","Value":[]}],"Reported":[]},"ETag":"AAAAAAAAAAQ="}

In a UWP app the function hangs and never returns any value.

This is the Code snippet:

```
            string connectionString = "...";
            RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

            try
            {
                var twin = await registryManager.GetTwinAsync(deviceId);
                Debug.WriteLine("Twin Data: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(twin));
            }
```

I am using VS 15.3.0 Preview 4.0.

I would expect all three projects to return exactly the same device twin data.
Am I confusing something here?

Comment: I get the same result from UWP app and console app. Where your code snippet locating, in a task?

Comment: The Code sits in an async Task. When I move it into the App class then it works nicely. Thanks for the tip but I don't understand the issue.

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662955/what-can-cause-getfileasync-to-hang).

Comment: Thank you for this - Any idea why JsonConvert.SerializeObject(twin) delivers different results in an Azure Function?